# how to use compass twitter bootstrap like compass blueprint

Tags: compass-sass

I have install the compass_twitter_bootstrap. i import it to my scss file like we import compass.

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass_twitter_bootstrap";
```

Importing compass is normal but while importing compass_twitter_bootstrap it overwrite all css in compiled css. Means all the css in bootstrap is imported to style.css. I want it to be work like compass file.

I am really noob in this compass and bootstrap. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to require it in your `config.rb`

```
require 'compass_twitter_bootstrap'
```

Comment: i had added the above code to my config.rb but whenever i import compass twitter bootstrap, it imports all the css at once. Can't we use only those css which we include using mixing like compass?

Comment: You'll have to dig into the extension to figure out how you want to import it. https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap/tree/master/stylesheets/compass_twitter_bootstrap If you want to use an import like a mixin you could always include the import further down in your sass file like a mixin.

Comment: I see it the way you do though, I always wrap my extensions with mixins per partial. I believe that it should be the designer's choice where to include the code.